# Overview questions about Cassandra's architecture

Tags: cassandra, architecture, nosql

I've been looking at Datastax's [Architecture in brief](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureIntro_c.html) web page (and a few others) but I found it didn't really answer key questions I had.  So I went ahead and wrote up an edited copy of the Datastax web page (see http://benslade.com/wordpress/?p=152, all feedback welcome).

I know I can figure things out by actually setting up a Cassandra database, but I don't like to have to figure out "what it does" for the user by having to figure out "how it's implemented" by the developer.

So, I have a few more questions about how thing work in Cassandra at an architecture level:

- The overview says, "data is distributed among all nodes in the cluster. Each node exchanges information across the cluster every second".  And later says a cluster is, "All writes are automatically partitioned and replicated throughout the cluster".   What is the relationship between a cluster and a data center? Ie. is a data center a part of an overall cluster. Do all nodes in all data centers exchange info with each other every second?  Does a write to any node in a particular data center get propagated to other data centers the same as it gets propagated in the current data center?
- The overview says "Once the memory structure (memtable) is full, the data is written to disk in an SSTable data file". Can the same data been in the memtable and the SSTable at the same time.  Ie. is the memtable a datacache for the SSTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, please try to limit your posts to one question at-a-time.

> What is the relationship between a cluster and a data center?

A cluster can contain one or more logical data centers.  Cassandra is data center-aware, which means you can alter your replication strategy on a per-data center basis.  Also, Cassandra has the concept of "locality," which means that the snitch can restrict a request to nodes in a particular data center.

EX: Querying by `LOCAL_QUORUM` will query data only from nodes in the data center that is determined to be the "closest" (network-wise).  Whereas querying by `QUORUM` will query from (N/2+1) nodes, regardless of data center (where N = node count).

> Do all nodes in all data centers exchange info with each other every second?

Again, the snitch handles the distribution of replicas and ensures that all nodes are kept current with the configured replication factor.  Of course as Cassandra embraces the Highly-Available, Partition Tolerant side of the CAP Theorem, all replicas operate on the concept of "Eventual Consistency."  Meaning, they will all get updated, but it may or may not happen before that data is requested.

> Does a write to any node in a particular data center get propagated to other data centers the same as it gets propagated in the current data center?

Yes, but again it depends on the configured replication factor.  Consider the following keyspace definition:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE stackoverflow WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'WestCoastDC': '2',
  'EastCoastDC': '3'
};
```

With this configuration, the snitch will ensure that a write to a replica in any data center will be propagated to my "WestCoastDC" until it has two copies of the data.  Likewise, my "EastCoastDC" will have three copies of the same data.  Note, your replication factor must be equal to or less than the number of nodes in that data center.

> Can the same data been in the memtable and the SSTable at the same
>   time. Ie. is the memtable a datacache for the SSTable?

I don't believe this can happen.  All writes in Cassandra should be written to the in-memory memtable, and simultaneously persisted on-disk via the commit log.  Then once your memtable threshold is reached, the memtable contents should be flushed and persisted to the SSTables.  Of course, if your node experiences a plug-out-of-the-wall event, the commit log will be verified and reconciled to ensure that its contents exist in the SSTables.